# Cordova Iframe issue

Tags: android, cordova, authentication, iframe, whitelist

Since using Cordova version 6, I have a siginificant problems using a Iframe. The Iframe-URL, I'm calling works fine in each browser, also in cordova-app on emulator. But on real devices, I have a really big problem using this Iframe.

What I'm doing:
Connecting to Qlik Sense Server (Qlik is a Business Intelligence Software) via Single API, using a link like this:

```
https://my-server.com/single/?appid=bba3d39c-4570-4056-8d49-5b64405647d8&sheet=kwZkH&select=clearall&opt=debug
```

Beacause, I'm not logged in yet, I will be automatically routet to this authentication site:

```
https://my-server.com:4244/form/?targetId=a0553562-06f5-4c5b-b4ba-69b6859d0cef
```

After logging in successfully, the URL turns back to the Single-API URL, extended with a qlikTicket for the session.

```
https://my-server.com/single/?appid=bba3d39c-4570-4056-8d49-5b64405647d8&sheet=kwZkH&select=clearall&opt=debug&qlikTicket=S_SPh6fvNkTecbz9
```

**So what's my real problem?** Since using the latest Cordova version 6, the redirection from authentication to the origin Single-URL crashes. The session is enabled for less than a second and then turns me back to authentication site.

This problem only occurs on real Android devices. Using the this link in browser, works. Using Iframe in browser, works. Trying out the cordova application on Android emulator, everything works fine! Trying out the cordova application on real Android devices, **doesn't work**!

**What's going wrong?**
Does have cordova any problems holding the qlikTicket in URL? Because I'm directly redirected to authentication site.

I know that there is a new security model since cordova 5. So I've implemented the cordova-whitelist-plugin and granted **all access to intents, navigation and acces**, as you can see here in my **config.xml**:

```
    <widget id="de.inform.feliosmobile4" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>FELIOSMobile</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<icon src="res/icon.png" platform="android" width="57" height="57" density="mdpi" />
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.3.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

This is what my **index.html** looks like(Iframe is build at the end of code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://*/*">
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <title>BeaconRanging</title>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 

    </head>
    <body>



    <!--    MONTAGE     -->
    <div class="popup" id="popupMONTAGE">
        <center>
            <div class="btnMachineGroup">Bitte Maschine wählen:</div>
            <br />
            <button class="btnMachineGroup" onclick="setRessource(421,'MONTAGE')">Montage Metall WA</button>
            <br />
            <button class="btnMachineGroup" onclick="setRessource(423,'MONTAGE')">Montage Metall AGW</button>
            <br />
            <button class="btnMachineGroup" onclick="setRessource(422,'MONTAGE')">Montage Metall GBK</button>
            <br />
            <button class="btnMachineGroup" onclick="setRessource(427,'MONTAGE')">Montage Spezialbohrkopf</button>
            <br />
            <button class="btnMachineGroup" onclick="setRessource(824,'MONTAGE')">Montage Service Metall</button>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button class="btnMachineGroup" onclick="hidePopup('MONTAGE')">Schliessen</button>
        </center>
    </div>

    <br /><br />
    <div class="container">
        <iframe id="qlikframe" src="https://my-server.com/single/?appid=bba3d39c-4570-4056-8d49-5b64405647d8&sheet=kwZkH&select=clearall&opt=debug"></iframe>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

So does anybody have an idea what is happening here and why? I've already contacted Qlik support. There is no problem from Qlik side.

... **Using cordova version 4, all ran perfectly and I had *no problems*. Building the same code in cordova 6, the app doesn't run as it should.**

What you can find in LOG-file from the Cordova-App is the following:

```
11-07 13:40:39.855 13009 13009 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(44)] "TypeError: Cannot redefine property: qlikTicket
```

So it seems, that the additional auth-info in URL (qlikTicket) gets lost. How to prevent this?

Comment: Any idea someone?

Comment: why don't you try with certificate authentication to qlik ticket  using [link] https://github.com/braathen/qlik-auth ?